# How to update the contents of a text input with d3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to create a text input control in D3 that needs to push data into the text input. I am able to set the initial value with

```
d3.selectAll('#textfield')
    .data([number])
    .attr('value', function(d) { return d })
```

but this is of no use once someone edits the text and then tries the external update. Is there some way of setting the contents to some arbitrary value?

I've got [the code in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hanbzu/LGtDD/).

Update:

I've found a [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/hanbzu/LGtDD/2/):

```
var node = d3.selectAll('#textfield')
    .data([number])
    .node()
node.value = number
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Any clues?

Comment: I didn't tag it with SVG because I am not using SVG in my code. It's plain HTML.

Comment: I did it for the badge :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *setting* the value of the `value` attribute and `value` just happens to be a special attribute which does not play well with `setAttribute` function (which `d3` internally uses for setting an attribute).

This approach is not much better, but more pragmatic use of `D3`:

```
d3.selectAll('#textfield')
    .data([number])
    .each(function (d) {
        this.value = d;
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LGtDD/3/

---

Besides, one can (and perhaps *should*) use plain JS to do this unless you have a compelling argument against it. Using D3 for this might just be overkill:

```
document.getElementById('textfield').value = number;
```

Comment: I use D3 in a more general context. This was only the failing part of what I wanted to do :) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text input value with

```
d3.select('#textfield').property('value', "<your desired text>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to works:

```
function changeValue() {
    var number = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    d3.select('#textfield')[0][0].value = number;
}
```